how to not reverse proxy root on nginx
I have the following nginx conf
without the server section it loads static index.html at / fine: http://fakedomain.com
I added the server/location section to reverse proxy back to an API at /patient.
The reverse proxy to API works, however going to / now gives me a 404
I recently added the / location in hopes that would work, but it did not.
Reverse proxy help does not seem to show how to map locations not to proxy?
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    server {
        location / {

        }
        location /patient/ {
            proxy_pass             http://localhost:3500/patient/;
            proxy_set_header       dapr-app-id get-patient-api;
        }
    }
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

How do get / to load static html like before and /patient/ to keep working as reverse proxy?

You are missing a root statement.
